# matlab function inside while loop

Tags: matlab

I've created this small program just for simplicity of the question, I am having some trouble using my function inside a while loop

this is the script;

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
while x<10
    y = func(x,y);
    x = x + 1;
```

this is the function, func;

```
function [] = func(x,y)

y- exp(-x)

end
```

I get the error of

```
Error using func
Too many output arguments.
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the function:

```
function [] = func(x,y)
```

You have specified that there will be no return values, yet when you call it you require a return value:

```
y = func(x,y);
```

To fix this issue you must alter your function declaration, e.g.:

```
function y_out = func(x,y)
```

Also, within your function declaration you have `y- exp(-x)`, which will not change the value of `y`; did you intend to have `y=exp(-x)`?

Comment: I want it to be f(x,y) = y - exp(-x), and return the value of f(x,y)

Comment: In which case the line should be `y_out = y - exp(-x);`